# Probability in limited Tennis Matches

Tags: probability

Rob and mike play a tennis match once a week.  No tennis matches end in a tie.  If it is raining they play indoors and if it is sunny they play outdoors.  When they play indoors the probability that Rob wins is 0.4 and when they play outdoors the probability that Rob wins is 0.6.  In the long run they play 30 percent of the matches indoors and 70 percent of the matches outdoors.  What is the expected number of matches that Rob will win in 10 randomly selected weeks next year?

Comment: Seems like the answer is 5 matches.  This using the Multiplication Rule of probability where we let p(a)=indoors and p(b)=outdoors.  We have:  0.4 X 0.30=0.12 and 0.6 X 0.70=0.42. But then I add these two values to get: 0.12 + 0.42= 0.54. These value times 10 matches:  0.54 X 10=5.4 or Rob wins 5 out of the 10 matches.  But I am troubled with adding the 0.12 and the 0.42.

Comment: Your calculation looks entirely correct. Think of it like taking a weighted average of how often a Rob wins inside vs outside.

Comment: Expectation can be non-integer even when the value itself must be integer. Thus it is not wrong to say that Rob is expected to win 1.2 indoor matches. What that means is that if you looked at a large number of such 10 match sets, the *average* number of indoor wins for Rob in each of them will be 1.2. And similarly for 4.2 outdoor matches. So the average number of Rob wins overall is 5.4. I.e., the *expected* number of matches is 5.4, not 5. But in a particular 10 match set, his is *most likely* to win 5 matches.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of win of Rob winning a match can be calculated by 
 P(Rob wins and plays indoor)+P(Rob wins and plays outdoor)
=P(plays indoor)*P(Rob wins|plays indoor) + P(plays outdoor)*P(Rob wins|plays outdoor)
=0.3*0.4+0.7*0.6
=0.54

As they play 10 matches, so using linearity of expectation, the expected match that Rob will win is =10*0.54 = 5.4